# How to find the length of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

```
 var legend=[{"min":0,
            "max":first_color,
            "color":"#1a9850"
  },
  {
      "min":first_color,
      "max":sec_color,
      "color":"#fee08b"
  },
  {
      "min":sec_color,
      "max":thrd_color,
      "color":"#ff3300"
  },
  {
      "min":thrd_color,
      "max":frth_color,
      "color":"#d73027"
      "Abc":"gsfg"
  }

  ];
```

I'd like to find out each object's property count. E.g. the first 3 objects have 3 properties and 4th one has 4 props, etc.

Comment: That's not JSON; that's a JavaScript array.

Comment: 1. Iterate 2. Get current element in array 3. `Object.keys(arrayEl).length`

Comment: can you post your code coz m new in js

Comment: What does "coz m" mean?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you having a problem looping over the elements/objects in the array? Are you having a problem getting the list of each object's keys?

Comment: Objects don't have "lengths". They have some number of properties.

Comment: Currently you have an array of Objects so 1. iterating over the array: `for(var i = 0; i < legend.length; i++)  { // Code that does something with each object here}`   2. find how many keys in that particular object - `Object.keys(legend[i]),length` OR iterate over each key and do something with it `for(var key in legend[i]){  console.log(legend[i][key]) }` 3. make it more readable - within 1. you could do `var currentLegend = legend[i];` then use that instead in 2. especially if you need to do more than just count the keys

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate over the array and get object property names count.

```js
var legend = [{
  "min": 0,
  "max": 'first_color',
  "color": "#1a9850"
}, {
  "min": 'first_color',
  "max": 'sec_color',
  "color": "#fee08b"
}, {
  "min": 'sec_color',
  "max": 'thrd_color',
  "color": "#ff3300"
}, {
  "min": 'thrd_color',
  "max": 'frth_color',
  "color": "#d73027",
  "Abc": "gsfg"
}];

var res = legend.map(function(v) {
  console.log(Object.keys(v).length);
  return Object.keys(v).length;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I really must remember to use map more +1 for a nice clean solution!

Comment: one more silly question what if i want to know which field are persent in json array in first there are min max and color and in fourth one min max color and Abc etc

Comment: coz for iterating object we must know key

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array of keys so you can iterate over that using either `map` again or a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @GauravSingh :  check `console.log(Object.keys(v))`

Comment: thx you so much..............

Answer (score 7):

- 'JSON' object is the wrong terminology.
- Referring to '[Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-or-associative-array)', the best solution would be:

  `Object.keys(obj).length`

But a better solution would be to prototype Object

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

Comment: Why is that a better solution?

Comment: @torazaburo Because it would be cleaner for more than 1 usage. Object.size(obj) is simpler and more human readable.

Answer (score 4):

you can use Object.keys

```
 console.log(Object.keys(legend[0]).length)// 3

 console.log(Object.keys(legend[3]).length);//4
```